# Установка ссылки на ссылку

Tags: c#

Есть некий класс Signal *(сильно упрощен, как и весь дальнейший код)*

```
public class Signal
{
    public int signalValue;
    public int address;
}
```

Программа читает конфигурационный файл, создает нужное количество экземпляров сигналов, каждый из них пользователь может независимо менять.

Далее - есть некий класс, описывающий какой-нибудь агрегат, имеющий входные\выходные сигналы, свою логику. В данном случае сигнал один. В описании логики механизма мы будем использовать именно его. Но сигнал можно привязать к одному из сигналов, которые ранее были считаны из конфигурации.

Так же есть форма, универсальная для всех механизмов. На ней через dataGridView выводим все сигналы. В гриде необходимо выводить определенные описания сигналов в зависимости от типа выбранного механизма, поэтому я завел класс SignalHolder, который содержит ссылку на сигнал и его описание.

```
public class SignalHolder
{
    Signal signal;
    string signalDescription;

    public SignalHolder(Signal signalArg, string descrArg)
    {
        signal = signalArg;
        signalDescription = descrArg;
    }
}


public class Mechanism
{
    public static List<Mechanism> mechanismList = new List<Mechanism>();

    public List<SignalHolder> signalHolderList = new List<SignalHolder>();

    public Signal someAcpSignal = new Signal();

    public Mechanism()
    {
        signalHolderList.Add(new SignalHolder(someAcpSignal, "Signal Description"));
    }
}
```

Все хорошо если сигнал из Mechanism не привязывать к сигналы из конфигурации. Под привязкой я подразумеваю что-то подобное:

```
Signal newSig = new Signal();
Mechanism m = new Mechanism();
m.someAcpSignal = newSig;
```

С этого момента Signal из SignalHolder не связан с someAcpSignal из Mechanism. Неужели необходимо каждый раз перестраивать signalHolderList, или есть способ корректно установить ссылку?

Comment: Может быть создать перегрузку конструктора с параметром Mechanism(Signal signal). Почему Вы так не хотите?
А коде создающий экземпляры механизма, уже сделать логику по выбору правильного конструктора

Comment: Еще можно создать второй приватный список. В него Вы будете помещать все те сигналы, которые привязывались. А при запросе signalHolderList, вы будете находить отличия, и на их основе уже выводить нужные данные.
Неплохо бы если Вы указали примерную нагрузку на систему.

Comment: @nuts119 в среднем у механизмов, которые надо реализовать, сигналов по 20. Наверное можно подумать в сторону передачи всех сигналов списками, но кроме этого нужна возможность перепривязки ссылок во время исполнения, поэтому через конструктор не выйдет.

Comment: А описание Signal из SignalHolder, и нового (привязанного: newSig) одно и тоже. Т.е. описание зависит только от механизма?

Comment: @nuts119 описание зависит только от механизма, после создания экземпляра SignalHolder изменяться не будет. Ресурсов будет много. Если я верно понял идею со вторым приватным списком, то проще будет сразу без него обновлять лист при каждой перепривязке.